# Classifier as compression

Tags: classification, nlp

Someone wrote a [Wordle clone in bash](https://gist.github.com/huytd/6a1a6a7b34a0d0abcac00b47e3d01513), using the full system dictionary. Unfortunately there is no smaller list of "common words" available locally to make use of.

I was wondering if a classifying algorithm/model could be used as a form of compression, to generate a list of common words at runtime in lieu of packaging a full list of common words.

It wouldn't need to be perfect, or even good (false negatives are absolutely fine, false positives less than ideal). Each user's (English) word list could be different, but is probably extremely similar, so I imagine overfitting is desirable. I guess the only important thing in this context is that it be small and portable, although portable POSIX shell script bit might be a tricky constraint.

What approach could you take?

Comment: Your description is similar to a bloom filter - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter. I am not sure this is what you are thinking though.